# Open forum in Tapatalk via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Does anyone know of a way to (detect and) open a forum in Tapatalk via Intents? My pseudo-approach would be as following, but I don't actually which intent to "use" for the given app:

```
try {

    startActivity(

        /* INTENT TO BE USED TO OPEN TAPATALK */  

    );        
    return;

} catch( ActivityNotFoundException ex ) {

    //Ignore the Exception as the user does not have Tapatalk installed 

}

startActivity( 

    new Intent( 

        Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("http://example.com")

     ) 

);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ehm... why did this get a downvote? 100% legit question if you ask me.

Comment: Would be really nice if some1 could give an answer to this, the tapatalk guys are no help at all: http://support.tapatalk.com/threads/android-intent-open-forum-with-tapatalk.11187/